# My site doesnt work in live mode

Tags: php, symfony

I have actually a problem with my site when i want to turn it in live mode. I have this error:

> Fatal error:  Class
>   'Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\LexikTranslationBundle' not found in
>   /home/maisonka/www/app/AppKernel.php on line 27

but I don't understand because my bundle lexik is in my vendor and `appKernel.php`  looks like:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Kayser\PlatformBundle\KayserPlatformBundle(),
        new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
        new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\LexikTranslationBundle(),
    );
```

Comment: Did you try to `php app/console clear:cache --env=prod` ?

Comment: I can't because i use filzila, i can't jsut delete app/cache

Comment: Why not? just delete them and symfony 2 will create a new cache

Comment: Do you have this bundle in vendor folder?

Comment: Finally the problem isn't due to my bundle. I had a bad conf in my config.yml

Comment: @cyber_truite don't let your question unanswered, post your comment as an answer (maybe more detailed) and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was my problem, I just deleted this line: `"new Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\LexikTranslationBundle(),"` and now everything works perfectly.